# How to get specific user input running inside a loop at n th Loop of entry

Tags: c

Here is my probleam comes with finding the **name of student with highest average**.I have found the highest average using node but i didn't have any idea about how I find the students name of highest average.Help me out to find the specific students name as output of highest average.

```
int main()
{
struct Node* head = NULL;
int math=0,phy=0,che=0,avg=0,cprg=0,n,i=1,sum=0,large;
char name[50], roll_no[20], dept[30];
FILE *file;
if (!file)
  {
    printf("File could not be opened\n\a\a");
    getchar();
    return -1;
  }
printf("\n How many students : ");
scanf("%d", &n);

while(i<=n)
 {
    printf("◻ NAME : ");
    scanf("%49s", name);
    printf("◻ DEPARTMET :");
    scanf(" %49s", dept);
    printf("◻ ROLL NUMBER :");
    scanf("%49s", roll_no);  
    printf("◻ MATHS MARK :");
    scanf(" %d", &math);
    printf("◻ PHYSICS MARK : ");
    scanf("%d", &phy);
    printf("◻ CHEMISTRY MARK :");
    scanf(" %d", &che);
    printf("◻ C Programming :");
    scanf(" %d", &cprg);
    printf("\n");
    avg = math+phy+che+cprg;
    avg=avg/4;
    append(&head, avg);
    i++;
}
printList(head);
file = fopen("first_mark.txt", "wt");
printf("%c",name);
fprintf(file,"%d",largest(head));
fclose(file);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: you need to post a [mcve]

Comment: Here's one way to do it (not necessarily the most efficient): define a variable for the index of the student, initialize it to `0`. Inside the loop test the recently calculated average against the average of student at index `index_student`; if it's higher, update `index_student` with the current working index. At the end of the loop, the `index_student` refers to the student with the highest average.

Comment: @pmg can you do that code I don't know how to do that...

Comment: If I do the code your teacher won't be able to know what parts you need help the most and you will not learn efficiently.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @pmg As I'm beginner in codeing I didn't get understanding in that part. So do some concernt do what need to be don't to get that specfic name or same come keyword to search about that.